# Unable to extract certificate and key from p12 file from azure key vault

Tags: azure, openssl, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

brief description what I've done and what I would like to achieve:

- I was trying to add certificate to azure key vault via UI:
- Got those certificates as ca.crt (`openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`) and ca.key (`openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048`) but azure key vault requires certificates in .pem or .pfx format
- I decided to move cert and key into pem format: key: `openssl rsa -in ca.key -text > ca_key.pem`
  cert: `openssl x509 -in ca.crt -out ca.pem` then copied ca_key.pem inside ca.pem
- I was trying with only cert + key and key extra data (binaries or sth)
- I was getting error from UI: `The specified PEM X.509 certificate content is in an unexpected format. Please check if certificate is in valid PEM format.`
- I decided to install azure CLI and pass those in pfx format: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out ca.pfx -inkey ca.key -in ca.crt` and that works properly I'm able to see created cert in key vault cerfiticates

and there problem begins. I would like to get certificate with azure node library, extract separate key and cert to use them. What I've achieved so far:

```
const secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, credential);
 
const certificateSecret = await secretClient.getSecret(certificateName);
 
const PKCS12Certificate = certificateSecret.value!;
 
fs.writeFileSync("myCertificate.p12", PKCS12Certificate);
```

I got file and as documentation says:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-certificates#getting-the-full-information-of-a-certificate

I was trying to execute:
`openssl pkcs12 -in myCertificate.p12 -out myCertificate.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys`
to extract ca certificate from p12 but I'm still getting error:

```
34359836736:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
34359836736:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS12
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?